# Universal Volume Control - Volume and BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Volume

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Are BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Volume and the Volume n/30 that is displayed in the Universal Volume Control (mango only) connected?

I can set the BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Volume value and whilst it does affect the Volume it does not change the n/30 figure in the UVC nor does it have the same level of control.

As an example setting BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Volume to 1.0 (the max) is has a different level of sound when the UVC is 30/30 than when the UVC is 5/30.

What should I be setting in the app to mirror the UVC controls?

Can I request the UVC be displayed via code? (I realise it is displayed when u press the hardware volume buttons)

Pat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't affect the volume as displayed in the UVC. The phone's volume is up to the user to control.
The volume you can set for the BAP (and for MediaElement) is the relative volume within the app. In theory, setting the UVC volume to 30 and the BAP volume to 0.5 should be equivalent to setting the UVC volume to 15 and the BAP volume to 1.0.

Unless you want/need the volume of what you're playing via the BPA (or MediaElement) to be quieter relative to the other sounds on the phone always set the BAP volume to 1.0.
You control the relative volume of things within your app. The user controls the volume of the phone overall.

No, you can't trigger the UVC to be displayed from code.

Comment: does BAP's volumne affect MediaElement's volume ?